# Bottom toolbar buttons flashes for a second?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

this little issue is really getting on me.

I have hierarchal navigation controller: RootView-->2ndListView-->DetailView

I implemented bottom toolbar with buttons easily on the DetailView. Works perfectly there.

However, in the 2ndListView, when I follow the same thing and put the following code in either viewdidload or viewwillappear or any other similar method, the button just flashes for a second when the view loads, and then hides.

Instead, if I put up this code in cellForRowAtPathIndex (so that nothing is executed after that), it does work. But this is obviously very inefficient.

So there is something happening in between.
What could be the issue?

```
NSMutableArray *array;
NSMutableArray *tags;

@implementation SMSListViewController


@synthesize smses,catID,addButtonItem,filteredSMS,searchBar,searchController;

-(void)getStarted{


    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    SMSDBAccess *smsDBAccess = [[SMSDBAccess alloc] init];

    smsDBAccess.catID = self.catID;

    self.smses = [smsDBAccess getAllItems];

    [smsDBAccess closeDatabase];

    [smsDBAccess release];    
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [array release];
    [smses release];
    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *addSMSButoon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(addSMS:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,addSMSButoon, nil];

    [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    [addSMSButoon release];
    [space release];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self getStarted];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [smses count];    
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    SMS *aSMS = [self.smses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text =aSMS.sms;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=aSMS.sms;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `navigationController` is shared between your whole navigation stack, so if there is a place where you are setting the `navigationController`'s items to `nil` (perhaps in a `viewDidDisappear` call) it would cause the items to go away after being set by the new view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but there is no code related to toolbar in RootView, and DetailView doesn't get executed by then. BTW, let me know if I should paste more code to help you find the issue.

Comment: Perhaps in IB? Maybe you can try setting a keyValue observer on the navigationController toolbar items. Then you will be notified of when it is being set to nil and you can figure it out from there,

Comment: I am a beginner & though I tried understanding it, I am unable to use keyValue Observer. Instead, I have edited my question to include the 2ndList.m. I have just pasted the code I thought is relevant to the ques. Please see if that helps!

Comment: No the code doesnt help. My guess is something is setting the items to nil, so the best course of action is for you to set a break point on anywhere this is called, anywhere in your code, then see what the value is when it is triggered, why it is called, and where it is being called from. This will lead you down the path to self-discovery.

Comment: Hey... thanks... although, I did not find the culprit, but while following your suggestion, I put up the code in viewDidLoad and it works!! (And I do not know how to mark your comment useful)